# PHP show no messages in GitBash under Windows 10

Tags: php, windows-10, git-bash

When I use cmd.exe everything is fine as usual
[image]

but in GitBash it looks like this

[image]

all commands are executing, but without any output.

How can I fix it? I tried different php versions, it did not help.

Comment: Can you check the value of the environment variable `TERM` (`echo $TERM`, in the bash session)? What version of Git are you using?

Comment: "echo $TERM" is "cygwin"

Comment: Can you try with `c:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.5.0-64-bit\git-bash.exe` (uncompress https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.5.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.5.0-64-bit.7z.exe in `C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.5.0-64-bit`)

Comment: Also, with your actual config, can you try and change `TERM`: `export TERM=msys` (just to test if that changes anything)

Comment: Github's git-bash.exe works well with php - http://savepic.org/7665759.png and `export TERM=msys` changed nothing in gitbash - http://savepic.org/7605340.png

Comment: Ok, what version of Git are you using? If it is not the 2.5, can you try the 2.5?

Comment: OK, can you try the 2.5 (no setup required, just uncompress https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.5.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.5.0-64-bit.7z.exe in C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.5.0-64-bit)

Comment: Did not change anything http://i.imgur.com/C9mF9sR.png

Comment: I suspect GitHub uses a Powershell session. What is the value of TERM in that GitHub shell session where php is working?

Comment: It's `xterm` in github's shell. Changing `TERM` value in both shells doesn't change the behavior of `php` in both shells. And, btw, it's only about `php`, other utils works fine in Gitbash.

Comment: What `which php` returns in those shells (1.9.5 or 2.5) What `alias php` returns? Would `php.exe -v` works the same? (Just checking if php actually means the php executable you think in those environments)

Comment: These values are same in both shells http://i.imgur.com/ZoYPcYm.png